# Redirecting to a url by appending query strings to it

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have to capture a query string at the starting of my survey, which i was able to do using php syntax. I now have the query string sitting in php.

My next task is to redirect to another URL at the end of my survey, BUT by appending the same query string I captured before.

For example, 
If I have a php field $user='abcdefgh';
And
I need to redirect to another link at the end, say https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow

By adding the query string $user. So the URL now becomes
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow?id=abcdefgh

Can someone guide me how to accomplish this.

I tried to do it using header in php, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Neeraj

Comment: Can you provide us some code what have you tried?

Comment: looking for this `$_REQUEST['id']` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
 $url = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow;
$user='abcdefgh';

header("location:".$url."?id=".$user);
```